# Fast conversion from np.float64 to np.uint8 (with scaling and clipping)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to find the fastest way to scale and convert the data type in python. This is one way to do it, however it is pretty slow:

```
# image is a large np.float64 image with values in an arbitrary range
timeit.timeit(lambda: np.clip(image*255, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8), number=100)
=> 4.746736011002213 seconds
```

I noticed that opencv has the function [convertScaleAbs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3460e9c9f37b563ab9dd550c4d8c4e7d) which does almost the right thing, but adds an unnecessary `abs` on top. This is much faster, but makes all negative values positive instead of zero:

```
timeit.timeit(lambda: cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=255, beta=0), number=100)
=> 0.7875663779996103 seconds
```

The [convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) function of `cv::Mat` would work as well, but this doesn't seem to exist in `python` land.

Any other ideas on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this bug regarding exactly that issue on the OpenCV bugtracker:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7231

It seems currently the fastest way to go is:

`cv2.addWeighted(image, alpha=255, src2=0, beta=0, gamma=0, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)`

which is a bit faster than the `convertScaleAbs` version.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is being copied both during the multiplication and during the `clip()`, if you can perform it in place it will speed it up a bit.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

side = 10000

source = np.random.random(side * side).reshape((side, side)) * 2 ** 16


def clip_1(image):
    return np.clip(image * 255, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)


def clip_2(image):
    image *= 255
    return np.clip(image, 0, 255, out=image).astype(np.uint8)


print('clip 1:', timeit.timeit(lambda: clip_1(source), number=10))  # 23.395304517
print('clip 2:', timeit.timeit(lambda: clip_2(source), number=10))  # 13.009874021000002
```

Or try using cv2 and restoring the sign after the fact:

```
clipped = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=0, beta=255)
clipped *= np.sign(image)
```